# Get Popup new target origin when screen edge is encountered

Tags: xaml, popup, wpf-controls

I have an issue with popup placement and especially the target origin.
I want to apply a Metro UI style to my combobox so there's no border between the textbox and the itemslist.

It works well when the popup is placed at the bottom

`Placement="Bottom"`

but when it encounters the bottom edge of the screen the target origin becomes the top of the placement target.

I'd like to know when the target origin changes to the top left corner, that way i could change the borderthickness of the control. Unfortunately the placement property is not reset to the new target origin so I'm a bit lost here.

Here's the code of the usercontrol.
The placement is set to custom here, it's the only workaround i've found to have something that suits me. But if I want metro like comboboxes I need to know where the popup really shows up...

```
    <Grid>
       <formElement:LabelBoxPC x:Name="NameFilter"
                            LabelName="{Binding FilterLabel,
                                                ElementName=UCInlineFilterPreSelected}"
                            TextBoxCommand="{Binding GoToEntityManagementCommand}"
                            TextBoxValue="{Binding SearchValue,
                                                   Mode=TwoWay,
                                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <formElement:LabelBoxPC.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="F4" Command="{Binding GoToEntityManagementCommand}" />
            </formElement:LabelBoxPC.InputBindings>
        </formElement:LabelBoxPC>
    <Popup x:Name="ResultsGrid"
             Placement="Custom"
             IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=NameFilter, Path=TextBoxFocus, Mode=OneWay}"
             AllowsTransparency="True"
             Focusable="False"
             PopupAnimation="None">
        <StackPanel>
            <Border Padding="5px" Background="#FFF" BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="2,2,2,0">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource SmallIconButton}" Background="{StaticResource DarkCloseIcon}"></Button>
            </Border>
            <ListBox x:Name="Results"
                 Width="220"
                 Style="{StaticResource InlineFilterListBox}"
                 Height="150"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, ElementName=UCInlineFilterPreSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

[image: Metro combobox]

Comment: you should add your code

Comment: Seems like more work than is necessary listening for the direction change. Why not just modify the control template directly and remove the border all together so it wouldn't care what direction it renders at and still have the same display?

Comment: What kind of control is your wrapper element? Is it Canvas?

Comment: i've edited the post.
@ChrisW.my I want my control to look like a metro UI combobox so I need these borders